# Display table-cell width percentages not obeyed

Tags: html, css

Why do the cells in the below example stretch fully collectively when it should only cover half the table width?

I've looked through numerous stackoverflow posts with similar issues, but none of their answers worked for me. And this is reflected in the below codepen example.

The reason why I'm trying to utilise table/table-cell for this is, because I will have elements, which will have variable heights. I can't have it zig-zag up and down using a float, and I don't want to set min/max-heights for the elements.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWMROW

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is a cell</li>
  <li>This is a cell</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Change `display: table;` to `display: table-row;`

Comment: this is the default implementation of display:table-cell. I would go with I display:inline-block; on all li tags

Comment: @j08691 I've tried this before posting this question, but it ignores the `width: 100%` on the table element.

Comment: @repzero Mimicking a tr/td, I want them to be even heights depending on each rows' tallest cell. From the looks of things, I don't think this is achievable with pure CSS and I might need to throw in some JS to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to mimick a tr/td, I believe a displaying the ul tag as `flex` can do the job. Also the width of the li tags can be set using css `flex`  property

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

ul li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex:0 0 25%;
  margin:0;
  border:solid red;
}
ul{
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  list-style-type:none;
}
li{
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is a cell</li>
  <li>This is a cell<br><br>addsd</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Completely forgot about flex! Thank you very much repzero.